# как изменить Fragment из activity?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Пробовал с помощью интерфейса, пробовал после создания фрагмента, обращаться к его методу, который обновлял бы текст. 
пробовал посылать TextView в фрагмент и обратно . 
Я не могу найти решения, подскажите как мне изменить текст фрагмента из активити?

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html

Answer (score 2):

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
YourFragmentClass fragment =
(YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
fragment.yourPublicMethod();
```

Вам нужно написать это в activity, который в хотите вызвать метод у фрагмента.

Если вы используете ViewPager, то можете вызвать через ViewPager.

```
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass )
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.view_pager + ":" + 0);
    fragment.yourPublicMethod();
```

Примерно так